# Memory Slowness issue with React Context and lot of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have a simple react app that load some external pdf page from api
Api send me result from page 1 its an array of all text of page sometimes there is 3000 text

```
{
  texts: [{ value: 'Title of page'}, {value:"Chapter 1"} ......
}
```

Render works good but after loading 50 pages my store is very heavy i have 3000 texts * 50 pages store in my context

I try to clean store to keep only last 10 pages but when i go back to page 1 i need to refetch the page and store it again in context

Do you have a solution other than context to avoid this performance issue (page lag when i scroll down to load another page) ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by memory issue? If it's a memory issue it's irrelevant where you store it in memory, context wouldn't make a difference. However 50 pages with "3000 texts" (not sure if this is chars or words) sounds fine in terms of memory. Not counting padding if that's chars it's only about 300kb.

Comment: No it's text with a lot a words, and the issue is scrolling that load new page become very slow after 10 or 15 page

Comment: Ok so it's a rendering issue not a memory one? Normally if you have pages you would render 1-2 at a time, or if rendering all of them virtualize the ones not visible